How to change vertical spacing between two minipages?
As you can see, in the image I included the pictures on the right are too far apart, resulting in the page they're supposed to be in to be skipped. The method I use is to wrap the different minipages I want in a figure like so :
\begin{figure}[h]
\minipage{0.65\textwidth}
    \lipsum[0-2]
\endminipage
\hfill
\minipage[t]{0.3\textwidth}    
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{poltocarele}
    \end{center}
\endminipage
\vfill
\hfill
\minipage[t]{0.3\textwidth}    
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{poltocarazi}
    \end{center}
\endminipage
\end{figure}

When it was only one figure and one block of text it worked fine, but now I want to have one big block of text and several figures. My current way of doing it is using \vfill but I think that's what results in the space being too big.


please edit your question and complete your code fragment. nobody can reproduce the output you show without (1) the images you have and (2) the paper and page layout you're using. either add draft to graphicx or use standard images everyone has such as example-image-a or cow. it's also not clear to me what layout you want here. if you want the second image alongside the text, you could wrap both images in a single minipage. it's also not clear what use figure is if you don't want it to float ....

@cabohah not convinced this is a duplicate of that one. if the OP is right about the problem, it might be, but it's hard to determine whether that's the case or not. we don't really know enough.

why are you using \minipage and \endminipage rather than \begin{minipage} and \end{minipage}? there is occasionally need to do something like this, but only very seldom. here it just seems egregious?

@cfr If he believes it's different, he should edit the question and make it clear. But I guess, if \vfill is too much vertical space information about other possible spaces could be useful.

thanks for the input everyone, that should give me enough to work with. I'm very new at LaTeX and have been basically making my document trying a lot of stuff until it did what I wanted it to do hence why it's so messy.

Your code is unnecessarily complicated. First, there's no need to encase the images in separate minipage environments; placing both images in a single minipage suffices. Second, the center environments don't do anything useful.
I also share @cfr's view about the (lack of) wisdom of using \minipage and \endminipage directives instead of employing minipage environments.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
  
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1-2] % not '[0-2]'
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation (0.05\textwidth)
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} % use a single 'minipage' for both graphs
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{poltocarele}

\vspace*{2cm} % set the desired vertical offset here

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{poltocarazi}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

